# Hystrix: Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix

I am using the [Spring Boot Admin Application](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) and I have a problem with the installation of the [Hystrix UI Module](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.4/#_hystrix_ui_module). I followed the installation instructions as you can see in the prevoius link!

**Here you can see my `pom.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>poc.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>wdp-spring-boot-admin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>wdp-spring-boot-admin</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Admin Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**And here my `application.properties` file:**

```
server.port=8888
spring.boot.admin.routes.endpoints=env,metrics,trace,dump,jolokia,info,configprops,trace,logfile,refresh,flyway,liquibase,heapdump,hystrix.stream
```

**When I try to open the Hystrix UI, I get the following error message:**

http://localhost:8888/#/applications/e6400bbe/hystrix

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to your application.yml file:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false 
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: hystrix.stream
      base-path: /
```

Then fire your REST endpoint a few times and check the `hystrix.stream`.

Answer (score 0):

you need add this in your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```